# HCE Phone-to-phone possibility after Android Beam Deprecation?

Tags: android, nfc, hce

Android Beam has been deprecated, so NFC Peer-to-peer isn't possible anymore. Is it possible to have two phones read/write HCE cards between each other to trigger an app to open and transfer the information through the app? I know back in 2017 someone asked this question and someone said it couldn't be done because Android Beam would override it, but if it's deprecated, I would think it could be done now, right?

[Host-based Card Emulation - Trigger a reader app when HCE is read on reader device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132193/host-based-card-emulation-trigger-a-reader-app-when-hce-is-read-on-reader-devi)

** Repost as a question since I previously posted this as an answer to someone's question, but I'm new to the community and I wasn't aware it needed to be its own q-post.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the question because it will resolve your problem ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Android Beam is deprecated in Android 10 only, it has not been removed from earlier OS's But I don't think Beam should have been a problem.

I've not tried this but it seems that https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid is what you are trying to achieve and the `readnfcmessage` app of that seems to have the Manifest Intent filters to be started by the HCE app, so it might be worth trying it out.